# wait image using javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to put a wit image (ie wait.gif) while using XMLHttpRequest?

I have a 'hidden' div called 'loader'.  Where do I change the display to block, and back to none?

Here is basically my code:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    ///Do Something with answer
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","gtservice01.php?s="+req01,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I am not ready to take the jquery jump yet.

Thx

R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function( ) { 
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
        //set display to none
        document.querySelector("div#loader").style.display="none";
        if(xmlhttp.status==200){ 
            //Do Something with answer 
        }
    } 
} 

xmlhttp.open("GET","gtservice01.php? s="+req01,true);
//set display to block
document.querySelector("div#loader").style.display="block";
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: I tried this....it stays as block,  but I am receiving data from the server via this request

Comment: I would remove the status==200 part, as any full response should hide the gif.

Comment: @MrM - I fixed the curly brace, as two were commented out, just in case that is an issue.